# Nested resultset in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am new in JSP. Presently i'm doing a simple project in JSP. In the project I want to fetch value from a table using a sql query and while display the values I want to check some value in another table. But this error shows.

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

My code is given below,

```
        <%
         String query3 = "SELECT * FROM flight WHERE  start_city='Kolkata' and end_city='Delhi'";
         ResultSet resultset3 = statement.executeQuery(query3);
        %>
        <table width="980" align="center" border="2" style="background-color: white;">
        <tr style="background-color: rosybrown; height: 30px;">
            <td>Flight Number</td>
            <td>Flight Name</td>
            <td>Start City</td>
            <td>End City</td>
            <td>Total Seat</td>
            **<td>Avaliable</td>**
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr> 
        <% while (resultset3.next()) {
        int tot_seat=resultset3.getInt(5);
        String query4 = "select sum(no_of_seat) from book where flight_id='"+resultset3.getString(1)+"'";
        ResultSet resultset4 = statement.executeQuery(query4);
        int book_seat=resultset4.getInt(1);
        %>                            
        <tr>
            <td><%=resultset3.getString(1)%></td>
            <td><%=resultset3.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%=resultset3.getString(3)%></td>
            <td><%=resultset3.getString(4)%></td>
            <td><%=resultset3.getString(5)%></td>
            **<td><%=tot_seat-book_seat%></td>**
            <td><%=resultset3.getString(6)%></td>
            <td>Remarks</td>
        </tr>
```

<% }%>